# How to auto expand and print a TreeView

Tags: delphi, printing, treeview, delphi-xe2

I created an application that goes out and scans every computer and populates a TreeView with Hardware, Software and updates/hotfixes information:

[image]

The problem I’m having is with printing, how do you automatically expand the treeview and sends the results of the selected computer to the printer? The method I am currently using involves sending the contents to a canvas (BMP) and then send it to the printer but that does not capture the whole treeview only whatever is being displayed on the screen.  Any advice?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Is just the text of the treeview formatted out properly or do you want the graphical view?

Comment: Not interested in the graphical view, just the text of the treeview and it would be nice if it was formatted out properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with printing the `TTreeView` is that the part that isn't visible has nothing to be drawn. (Windows draws only the visible portion of the control, so when you use `PrintTo` or the API `PrintWindow` function, it only has the visible nodes available to print - the non-displayed content hasn't yet been drawn and therefore can't be printed.)

If a tabular layout works (no lines, just indented levels), the easiest way is to create text and put it in a hidden `TRichEdit`, and then let the `TRichEdit.Print` handle the output. Here's an example:

```
// File->New->VCL Forms Application, then
// Drop a TTreeView and a TButton on the form.
// Add the following for the FormCreate (to create the treeview content)
// and button click handlers, and the following procedure to create
// the text content:

procedure TreeToText(const Tree: TTreeView; const RichEdit: TRichEdit);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  Indent: Integer;
  Padding: string;
const
  LevelIndent = 4;
begin
  RichEdit.Clear;
  Node := Tree.Items.GetFirstNode;
  while Node <> nil do
  begin
    Padding := StringOfChar(#32, Node.Level * LevelIndent);
    RichEdit.Lines.Add(Padding + Node.Text);
    Node := Node.GetNext;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HideForm: TForm;
  HideEdit: TRichEdit;
begin
  HideForm := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    HideEdit := TRichEdit.Create(HideForm);
    HideEdit.Parent := HideForm;
    TreeToText(TreeView1, HideEdit);
    HideEdit.Print('Printed TreeView Text');
  finally
    HideForm.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  RootNode, ChildNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  RootNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(nil, 'Root');
  for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    ChildNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(RootNode, Format('Root node %d', [i]));
    for j := 1 to 4 do
      TreeView1.Items.AddChild(ChildNode, Format('Child node %d', [j]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This answer is not bad, but at least in Lazarus there is already a method for TTreeView like SaveToFile which will save a tab deleimited text file for you.  (Still, the above method would be good for generating a fixed layout file, HTML, etc.)